# Gradle task for updating a file inside a WAR file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have SpringBoot project that generates both a [deployable and an executable WAR file using the SpringBoot Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal). I want to update a `.properties` file inside of both WAR files. My files look like this:

```
build/libs/my-app-1.0.0.war
  ...
  /WEB-INF/classes/file.properties
  ...

build/libs/my-app-1.0.0-boot.war
  ...
  /WEB-INF/classes/file.properties
  ...
```

I want to update a single key inside the `properties` file or completely replace the file. Either solution would work.

These are the versions:

- Gradle 6.2.2
- SpringBoot 2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: This is called resource filtering, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328132/is-resource-filtering-in-gradle-possible-without-using-tokens

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by 
modifying [the answer linked by @Lesiak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328132/is-resource-filtering-in-gradle-possible-without-using-tokens) in the comments as follows:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/file.properties') {
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens,
                tokens: [replace-token: project.property('replace-value').toString()])
    }
}
```